# ¿Qué significa "-m" en "git commit -m"?

Tags: git, git-commit

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Git y para dejar un `commit`, usan el comando `git commit -m`. Entiendo lo primero, pero no sé que significa ni para que sirve el `-m`

¿Alguien me lo puede explicar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UNA VEZ que tienes listos los cambios a los cuales les harás seguimiento con Git, significa lo siguiente

1. `commit`: enviar las actualizaciones que hiciste es decir poner bajo seguimiento
2. `-m`: agregas un mensaje que identifique que cambios llevaste a cabo, será un texto que aparezca en tú histórico de commits y te ayudará a identificar que cambios a agregaciones hiciste

> tus archivos pasan por tres estados: stage, commit y push que es
>   cuando los mandas a tu repositorio

**EJEMPLO**

Creas un index.html al que le agregas unos estilos css para que tenga un fondo de color, primero haces(lo siguiente es un ejemplo depende de como estes trabajando, si es por ejemplo con gitlab o github), pero a modo general

1. `git init`
2. `git add .` (para agregar todos los archivos al stage)
3. `git commit -m "Mi primer avance del trabajo de desarrollo web"`
4. `git push` (envias tus archivos a tu repositorio remoto)